# Cannot edit data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I create this page to edit data from database but Its keep pooping up validation error after I click the submit button to fill all forms but I already fill all forms. Please help me.

```
include('conn.php');

// creates the edit record form

// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable

function renderForm($noid, $listVendor, $department, $district, $report, $error)

{


// if there are any errors, display them

if ($error != '')

{

echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';

}


}



// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

{

// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data

if (is_numeric($_POST['noid']))

{

// get form data, making sure it is valid

$noid = $_POST['noid'];

$listVendor = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['listVendor']));

$department = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['department']));

$district = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['district']));

$report = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['report']));




// check that all fields are filled in

if ($listVendor == '')

{

// generate error message

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';



//error, display form

renderForm($noid, $listVendor, $department, $district, $report, $error);

}

else

{

// save the data to the database

mysql_query("UPDATE tblvendorreport SET listVendor='$listVendor', department='$department', district='$district', report='$report' WHERE noid='$noid'")

or die(mysql_error());



// once saved, redirect back to the view page

header("Location: bdl-VendorReport.php");

}

}

else

{

// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error

echo 'Error!';

}

}

else

// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form

{



// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)

if (isset($_GET['noid']) && is_numeric($_GET['noid']) && $_GET['noid'] > 0)

{

// query db

$noid = $_GET['noid'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblvendorreport WHERE noid=$noid")

or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);



// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the database

if($row)

{



// get data from db

$listVendor = $row['listVendor'];

$district = $row['district'];

$report = $row['report'];




// show form

renderForm($noid, $listVendor, $department, $district, $report,'');


}

else

// if no match, display result

{

echo "No results!";

}

}

else

// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error

{

echo 'Error!';

}

}
```

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor has been **deprecated since 2013** (in PHP 5.5), and is **removed in PHP 7** (released in 2015). This is because it has **serious** security vulnerabilities. **DO NOT USE IT**. Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Include the code that generates the form. That seems to be missing from your code above. All I see is the error message div. Also check that you have action=post on your form tag and that the spelling and capitalization of the "listVendor" field match in the form and in the code.

Comment: Can you share the error message? is it coming in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrote for your original bet, otherwise, show this error

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
function renderForm($noid, $listVendor, $department, $district, $report, $error){
if ($error != ''){
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}else{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:green;">'.$noid.'<br>'.$listVendor.'<br>'.$department.'<br>'.$district.'<br>'.$report.'</div>';
}
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  // if method post
if (is_numeric($_POST['noid'])){  // if is numeric
$noid = $_POST['noid'];
$listVendor = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['listVendor']));
$department = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['department']));
$district = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['district']));
$report = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['report']));

if ($listVendor == ''){
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($error);
}else{
mysql_query("UPDATE tblvendorreport SET listVendor='$listVendor', department='$department', district='$district', report='$report' WHERE noid='$noid'")
or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: bdl-VendorReport.php");
}
}else{  // if is not numeric
$error = 'Error!';
renderForm($error);
}
}else if ((isset($_GET['noid'])) AND (is_numeric($_GET['noid'])) AND ($_GET['noid']>0)){ // if method get
$noid = $_GET['noid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblvendorreport WHERE noid=$noid")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(@$row){
$listVendor = $row['listVendor'];
$district = $row['district'];
$report = $row['report'];
$department = $row['department'];
$error = '';
renderForm($noid,$listVendor,$department,$district,$report,$error);
}else{
$error = 'No results!';
renderForm($error);
}
} // else if
?>
```